# How to add a list of unique values from a column to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So have I some code that creates a new dataframe that counts the number of unique states with at least 1 non null value and the total number of non null values grouped by year. Code works fine, but I want to modify it to include a new rows that lists the unique states.

This is my data:

```
    year    state   var1    var2    
0   2018    CA       NaN     2    
1   2018    TX       1       NaN    
2   2018    FL       NaN     NaN  
3   2018    AL       1       2    
4   2018    AL       NaN     1   
6   2019    CA       NaN     NaN  
7   2019    TX       1       1    
8   2019    FL       NaN     NaN  
9   2019    AL       2       1    
10  2019    AK       2       NaN
```

This my current output:

```
                                                          2018     2019
var1
      Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:   2        3
      Number of respondents with non-null var:            2        3
      Average:                                            1        1
var2
      Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:   2        2   
      Number of respondents with non-null var:            3        2
      Average:                                            1.5      1
```

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
c = df.groupby(['year', 'state']).count()
res = c.groupby('YEAR').agg([np.count_nonzero, sum]).T
res.index = res.index.set_levels(['Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:', 
                                  'Number of respondents with non-null var:'], level=1)

z = res.swaplevel().T
res4 = pd.concat([z, pd.concat([z['Number of respondents with non-null var:'] / 
                                z['Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:']], 
                              keys=['Average:'], axis=1),], 
                axis=1).T.swaplevel().sort_index()
```

And this is what I want the new output to look like:

```
                                                          2018         2019
var1
      Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:   2            3
      Unique states with at least 1 non-null:             [TX, AL]     [TX, AL, AK]
      Number of respondents with non-null var:            2            3
      Average:                                            1            1
var2
      Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:   2            2   
      Unique states with at least 1 non-null:             [AL, CA]     [TX, AL]
      Number of respondents with non-null var:            3            2
      Average:                                            1.5          1
```

Basically I want this row included "Unique states with at least 1 non-null:", listing the names of the states. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create new function `f` for `states` and also aggregate `mean` for label in MultiIndex, values are set by division selected rows by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), last `rename` for new second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
c = df.groupby(['year', 'state']).count()

def f(x):
    return x.index[x.ne(0)].droplevel(0).tolist()

df = c.groupby(['year']).agg([np.count_nonzero,f,'sum', 'mean']).T
df11 = df.xs('sum', level=1, drop_level=False).div(df.xs('count_nonzero', level=1), level=0)
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'mean'],:] =  df11.rename({'sum':'mean'}).astype(np.float64).round(1)

d = {'count_nonzero':'Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:', 
     'sum':'Number of respondents with non-null var:',
     'f':'Unique states with at least 1 non-null',
     'mean':'Average:'}
df = df.rename(d)
print (df)
year                                                        2018          2019
var1 Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:         2             3
     Unique states with at least 1 non-null             [AL, TX]  [AK, AL, TX]
     Number of respondents with non-null var:                  2             3
     Average:                                                1.0           1.0
var2 Number of unique states with at least 1 non-null:         2             2
     Unique states with at least 1 non-null             [AL, CA]      [AL, TX]
     Number of respondents with non-null var:                  3             2
     Average:                                                1.5           1.0
```

Comment: I attempted to use your function on my full dataset and I'm getting the following error: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Comment: @miqcrom26 - What code raisse error? `df11 = df.xs('sum', level=1, drop_level=False).div(df.xs('count_nonzero', level=1), level=0)` ? What is your pandas version?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the part that's giving me problems. I currently using pandas version 1.3.5

Comment: @miqcrom26 - Can you try `df11 = df.xs('sum', level=1, drop_level=False).div(df.xs('count_nonzero', level=1).replace({ 0 : np.nan }), level=0)` instaed `df11 = df.xs('sum', level=1, drop_level=False).div(df.xs('count_nonzero', level=1), level=0)` ?

Comment: Perfect! One last thing, I'm trying to round off the 'Average' value to 1 decimal place using `df = df.round(1)` on the entire dataframe, but it's not working. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @miqcrom26 - Use `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean'], :] =  df11.rename({'sum':'mean'}).round(1)` instead `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean'], :] =  df11.rename({'sum':'mean'})`

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I tried that and it's still not rounding

Comment: @miqcrom26 Can you explian more? What does it mean?

Comment: For example, I have value of 2772.972973 and after running `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean'], :] =  df11.rename({'sum':'mean'}).round(1)` the returned value is still 2772.972973

Comment: @miqcrom26 - You are right, tested. For me working `df11.rename({'sum':'mean'}).astype(np.float64).round(1)
`